# Updating product name/description (that has group prices) via model causes Integrity constraint violation (in catalog_product_entity_group_price)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, model

I have this simple code, which tries to update the product's `name` & `description` like this:

```
$productID = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getIdBySku($product->Sku);

if ($productID)
{
    $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
    $p->load($productID);
    $p->setName($product->Name);
    $p->setDescription($product->Description);
    $p->save();
    $p = null;
}
```

This causes the following error to occur:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '3596-0-1-0' for key 'CC12C83765B562314470A24F2BDD0F36', query was:
>   INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_group_price` (`entity_id`,
>   `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `value`, `website_id`) VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?)

I've noticed this error only occurs IF the product has `group_price` set on it (even though I am not updating this).

Any ideas? I am on magento `1.9.x`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have solved it like this: *hope this helps someone else with similar issue...*

```
// Update Existing Product
$productAction = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->getResource();
$productAction->updateAttributes(array($productID), array(
    'name' => $product->Name,
    'description' => $product->Description
), 0); // 0 = store id (default scope)
$productAction = null;
```